# Looping through multiple files on import using PapaParse

Tags: javascript, input, papaparse

I wrote a small backend for my application where I can upload csv's. It needs to go through the csv's and parse them into JSON. I am using PapaParse for this and I can do one file. However I need to upload multiple files and have them parse. I can upload the files however I cannot figure out how to select all of the files.

Here is my code: HTML

```
<form class="import">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" class="form-control-file" id="fileToRead" multiple>
            <small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">You can enter one day or multiple days. Please see another import for anything other than daily data</small><br>
        </div>
    <!-- this line... the id is in the importData.js file, overflow-y: auto is what makes this section scrollable-->
    <p id="editor" style="border: 1px black dotted; width: 100%; height: 200px; overflow-y: auto;">Hopefully see something here</p>
    </form>
```

Here is the js file:

```
//Getting the document by the ID and when something changes it runs the function
document.getElementById("fileToRead").addEventListener("change",function(){
    //creates a var for the first file.



 var files = this.file[0]

       Papa.parse(files, {
       header:true,
       dynamictyping:true,
       complete:function(results){
           console.log(results);
           var data = results.split;
           document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = data;
       }
       });
    //this prints the value of the evt.target.result (which is another pre-defined JS object that runs with
    //FileReader woo hoo!)  this has to have .innerHTML becuase I have a <p> tag, when it was a <textArea> it had
    // to have .value

  });
```

I am pretty sure it has to do with the first line in the JS only selecting file 0 however I have tried empty brackets and a few other things and its still only outputs one object.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I figured it out. I was confused on how to loop through all of the documents and here is the code that fixed it.

```
document.getElementById("fileToRead").addEventListener("change",function(){
//creates a var for the first file.
//Gets the number to loop through
var input = document.getElementById("fileToRead");
console.log(input.files.length);
for(var i = 0; i < input.files.length; i++){
    var files = input.files[i];
               Papa.parse(files, {
               header:true,
               dynamictyping:true,
               complete:function(results){
                   console.log(results);
                   document.getElementById("editor").innerHTML = "stuff";
               }
               });
```

1) create a variable called input that grabs all the files

2) I console.log it so that I knew I was grabbing all the files, you need to add files.length to the input because you are looking for all of the files in that input. files is a word that is pre-defined that we can use!

3) then just looped through the files using input.files.length as I had done for console.log because I knew that worked. I guess I could have created a variable but whatever.

4) the var files inside the for loop is used with [i] because as the for loop goes through it will populate the value for [i] it starts with 0 so it will start with the first document and then go through the rest until there are none left.

5) Use PapaParse to go through the files.

In the compete:function(results) part I am using a console.log so I know the code got down here. That last bit of code document.getElementByID is because I wanted to see what it was outputting. This is not currently working, but it does output "stuff as I have it there.

I hope this helps someone else trying to do something like this.